# How to create a bar chart of 20 most profitable products from a dataset using jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table Sales that contains several columns. To get the total revenue for every product I multiply the unit_price*quantity. Then I drop all of the columns except product_id and the new column (total_revenue) but when I try to visualize the 20 most profitable products, my barchart displays the product_id as a value and includes it in the visualization (it should be a label instead).

[image: The table I work with]
[image: The visualization I get]

The code I used after connecting the notebook to the DB is:

```
Sales['total_revenue'] = Sales['unit_price']*Sales['quantity']

Sales = Sales.drop(['sales_id', 'unit_price', 'quantity', 'due_date', 'ship_date', 'discounted'], axis=1)

Sales = Sales.sort_values(['total_revenue'], ascending=False)

Sales.iloc[:20].plot(kind='bar', figsize=(20,5))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `"product_id"` as an index with [`pandas.DataFrame.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) :

```
Sales.iloc[:20].set_index("product_id").plot(kind="bar", figsize=(6,3))
```

[image]